# python pandas download and rename

Tags: python, csv, selenium

I have a csv file called (data.csv). this csv file contain 2 columns the first called (title) and the other called (link).

This code purpose is to open every URL in link column and download the file linked to it. Then rename it with the string in title column which is in the very same row.

For any reason if the file did not downloaded the code should pass the whole row.
And start again in the next row till the list is finished.

here is the data:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5bJvxM9TZkhVGI5dkdLVzAyNTA

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Sayed\\Downloads")

titles = df['title']
links = df['link']

for event in links:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(event)

    # download
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fxec_historytable"]/a').click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fxec_historytable"]/a')))

for file, name in zip(os.listdir(), titles):
    fileName = os.path.splitext(file)
    os.rename(file, name)
```

The download part is ok with no problem but there is no renaming at all.

Comment: if you want to apply each title to each file you might need to use single loop `for file, name in zip(os.listdir(), titles):`

Comment: @Andersson still no renaming

Comment: Your code is working for me. Are you sure titles contains valid file names with the extension?

Comment: @Isma check  the data your self i added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your script so you can specify the download folder, instead of having to work in your users download folder.

Also, you can rename the files while you download them, then you make sure you rename the right one.

Another improvement is to create only one instance of the Webdriver as opposite of a new instance on every iteration of the for loop.

Finally, you were not adding the extension when renaming the file, which I think was the cause of the renaming error.

Here is the modified version, make sure the output folder is empty before running it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import pandas as pd
import os

default_dir = r"C:\temp\Test"

df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\temp\data.csv')
os.chdir(default_dir)

titles = df['title']
links = df['link']

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": default_dir,
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome("c:/temp/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)

for idx, event in enumerate(links):
    driver.get(event)
    # download
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fxec_historytable"]/a').click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fxec_historytable"]/a')))

    while not os.path.exists(os.path.join(default_dir, "history.csv")):
        pass

    # assumming the file is called "history.csv"
    file = os.path.join(default_dir, "history.csv")
    os.rename(file, titles[idx] + ".csv")
```

[image: Here is the output]

Comment: after a couple  of links downloaded there is an error raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sayed/PycharmProjects/Tutorial/us.py", line 40, in <module>
    os.rename(file, titles[idx] + ".csv")
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\Sayed\\Desktop\\data\\history.csv' -> 'Industrial New Orders s.a. (MoM) - European Monetary Union.csv'

Comment: I modified my answer, now I used a while loop to wait until the file is available so we will get the maximum possible speed an no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore previous edits. 
Wrong code, wrong place, wrong question.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you provided some narrative around your answer and not just the `comments` in the code.